# Check if FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver is installed via system properties?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a set of web tests that run in various browsers. I want to skip a test if the corresponding driver isn't installed.

However, these tests that will be executed by different machines,meaning OS and driver setups will differ. I was wondering if there was some way to use JUnit.assumeNotNull() to check if the system propery values for the driver are not null?

For instance:

```
@Before
public void checkForDriver() {
    assumeNotNull(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
}
```

or

```
@Before
public void setupCheck() {        
    assumeNotNull(System.getProperty("webdriver.safari.driver"));
}
```

This works for chrome and others, but for firefox I've been checking both "webdriver.firefox.bin" and "webdriver.firefox.driver" and the test still skips. I know that firefoxDriver should be working fine(the test runs and passes if i remove the assumption).

Any advice or another good method to check that a driver/browser is installed?

Comment: What you will do for Safari driver? Where the Driver is installed as an plugin to the Safari browser?

Comment: I added an example of what I use for safari @Ant's

Answer (score -1):

In order to run Selenium with IE or Chrome, you need to install some extra binary on your test client machine. In contrast, [FirefoxDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) is an integral part of Selenium. So if you run Selenium, a test whether FirefoxDriver is installed does not really make sense.

In case Firefox as a browser is not installed on your test client machine, you should probe for **Firefox browser** sytem properties, as opposed to **FirefoxDriver**.

Comment: This was related to a tests in a framework, not with a client in mind. Dealing with the case of someone downloading the framework and running the tests, and in the case of ie driver, when building remotely.


I actually check for both the driver and the browser since they are both required